# Apache Beam: Reading from Kafka starting at the initial offset rather than the latest

Tags: apache-kafka, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am trying to write a simple Beam pipeline that starts consuming data from the earliest offsets existing in the partitions of each Kafka Topic.

I have not been able to figure out how to consume data from the earliest possible offsets in a topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, `KafkaConsumer` instances will try to consume data from the *latest* offset for each partition. This means they'll start consuming only new messages published to the topic.

If you want your pipeline to start by consuming the **earliest available Kafka offsets**, then you can achieve this by calling `withStartReadTime` parameter:

```java
p.apply(KafkaIO.read()
    .withBootstrapServers(KAFKA_BOOTSTRAP_SERVER)
    .withTopic(KAFKA_TOPIC)
    // By reading data from EPOCH, you'll ensure the earliest messages are consumed
    .withStartReadTime(Instant.EPOCH))
```

And that should do it!